# how can i find the second minimum value in MIPS?

Tags: arrays, mips, minimum

In this project you will implement a MIPS application
which finds the second minimum value
in the declared array. Below how an integer array can be defined is given.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJetM.png)

values
contains the array elements and size de scribes the l ength of the array.

Some example arrays and expected output are give
n below.

Array: [13 , 16 , 16, 7, 7]
Your ouput:13

Array: [ 8, 8, 8]
Your ouput: There is No Second Smallest

Array: [ 7, 7, 6]
Your ouput: 7

Array: [ 8, 7]
Your ouput: 8

Array: [3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 5]
Your ouput: 5

Comment: Sort the array in ascending order using whatever sorting algorithm you want, then iterate over the sorted array until you find an element that does not equal the first element, or you reach the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to the problem with comments to explain.

I have not implemented the special case of the values all being the same but it would not be a very difficult addition. Just a final `beq $a1, $a2, end`

I have many more special cases in here as well, such as checking if there exists a value in the reserved spaces for the smallest and second smallest.

There is also no user input taken as it was unclear if that was the final intention.

```
.data


values: .word 13 , 16 , 16, 7, 7   # Array contents

.text


main:
    li $a0, 5           # Loading array size
    la $a3, values
    
    move $a2, $zero     # Second Smallest
    move $a1, $zero     # Smallest
        
                
    loop: 
    
        beq $t1, $a0, fin       # If iterator is equal to the high value entered break
        lw $t5, 0($a3)          # Loading the element at the given array address
    
        bnez $a2, sSmallestExists   # Branch if $a2 has a value -- there is a second smallest value
        bnez $a1, smallestExists    # Branch if $a1 has a valuel -- there is a smallest value 
        move $a1, $t5           # Set $a1 to the value stored at $t5 -- set the smallest value
        j reloop            # jump to reloop

    smallestExists:
        blt $t5, $a1, setSmallest   # Branch if the current value is less than the smallest value
        move $a2, $t5           # Set the second smallest to the current value
        j reloop            # jump to reloop

    sSmallestExists:
        bge  $t5, $a2, reloop       # If the current value in $t5 is greater than the second smallest reloop
        blt  $t5, $a1, setSmallest  # Branch if the current value in $t5 is less than the smallest
        beq  $t5, $a1, reloop       # If the current value in $t5 is equal to the smallest reloop
        move $a2, $t5           # Set the second smallest to the current value
        j reloop
    
    setSmallest:
        move $a2, $a1           # Set the current smallest value ($a1) to be the second smallest ($a2)
        move $a1, $t5           # Set the current value ($t5) to be the smallest ($a2)
    
    reloop:
        addi $t1, $t1, 1        # Add one to the iterator
        add $a3, $a3, 4         # Add 4 to progress the array
    
        j loop          # Go back to the top of the loop

fin:

    li $v0, 1           # Output second smallest value
    la $a0, ($a2)
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 10          # Syscall 10 to indicate end of program
    syscall
```